# Navigation Drawer remove horizontal start & end padding

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How to remove horizontal right/left padding in `NavigationDrawer` icons?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

1. **For the icon start/left padding**

   **Programmatically**

   ```
    navigationView.setItemHorizontalPadding(0);
   ```

   **XML**

   ```
    app:itemHorizontalPadding="0dp"
   ```
2. **For the icon end/right padding**

   **Programmatically**

   ```
    navigationView.setItemIconPadding(0);
   ```

   **XML**

   ```
    app:itemIconPadding="0dp"
   ```

[image]